# AndEngine example not working

Tags: andengine, augmented-reality, game-center, git-branch

I really need to use this example for my app:
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/examples/AugmentedRealityExample.java (Nicolas personally suggested me so), but it doesn't work. I mean, I'm using GLES2-AnchorCenter branch, but seems like no "SimpleBaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity" exist, so I can't extend that and I get an error when I use 
import org.andengine.extension.augmentedreality.SimpleBaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity;

what am I doing wrong?? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the GLES2-AnchorCenter branch using

`git clone https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension.git -b GLES2-AnchorCenter`.

Adding this as a project in Eclipse (I'm assuming you did the same for the AndEngine GLES2-AnchorCenter branch) will auto-build the JAR file for you in the bin folder. You can use that JAR file in your project as it contains the SimpleBaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the jar file for the Augmented Reality extension into the project's build path. Personally, even that didn't work for me, so I just added the source code from the project's page [here](http://code.google.com/p/andengineaugmentedrealityextension/) to my app as Java classes and everything worked perfectly after that.

Comment: That version is one year old. The current repositories are at https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineAugmentedRealityExtension